# Remove leading zeros

Tags: sql, db2

Given data in a column which look like this:

```
00001 00
00026 00
```

I need to use SQL to remove anything after the space and all leading zeros from the values so that the final output will be:

```
1
26
```

How can I best do this?

Btw I'm using DB2

Comment: are you also looking for ways to trim everything after the space after `26`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was tested on DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows and z/OS.

You can use the [`LOCATE()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000820.html) function in DB2 to find the character position of the first space in a string, and then send that to [`SUBSTR()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000854.html) as the end location (minus one) to get only the first number of the string.  Casting to `INT` will get rid of the leading zeros, but if you need it in string form, you can `CAST` again to `CHAR`.

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(col, 1, LOCATE(' ', col) - 1) AS INT)
FROM tab
```

Comment: @bhamby This returns a numeric value, it looks like the questioner wants a left adjusted alpha field. A TRIM(L '0' from col) will do the trick. It will also run into trouble when the field doesn't contain a space. A simple || ' ' can be added to both "col" to avoid this...

Answer (score 3):

In DB2 (Express-C 9.7.5) you can use the SQL standard [`TRIM()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0023198.htm) function:

```
db2 => CREATE TABLE tbl (vc VARCHAR(64))
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => INSERT INTO tbl (vc) VALUES ('00001 00'), ('00026 00')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => SELECT TRIM(TRIM('0' FROM vc)) AS trimmed FROM tbl

TRIMMED                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------
1                                                               
26                                                              

  2 record(s) selected.
```

The inner `TRIM()` removes leading and trailing zero characters, while the outer trim removes spaces.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't remove the trailing. 00001 00 --> 1 00

Comment: @Bob, are there trailing spaces *after* the zeroes?  I can only test with Ora/My/Pg/FB, but the DB2 docs describe compliant behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on the AS400 DB2.
The "L" stands for Leading.
You can also use "T" for Trailing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the field type is currently `VARCHAR`, do you need to store things other than INTs?

If the field type was `INT`, they would be removed automatically.

Alternatively, to select the values:

```
SELECT (CAST(CAST Col1 AS int) AS varchar) AS Col1
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread for some reason and find it odd that no one actually answered the question. It seems that the goal is to return a left adjusted field:

```
SELECT 
       TRIM(L '0' FROM SUBSTR(trim(col) || ' ',1,LOCATE(' ',trim(col) || ' ') - 1))
  FROM tab
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is implicit casting: `SELECT SUBSTR(column, 1, 5) + 0 AS column_as_number ...`

That assumes that the structure is **nnnnn nn**, ie exactly 5 characters, a space and two more characters.

Explicit casting, ie SUBSTR(column,1,5)::INT is also a possibility, but exact syntax depends on the RDBMS in question.

Comment: It doesn't work. It converted 00001 00 as 1 but 00026 00 as blank.

Comment: @Bob just curious, what database are you using?

Comment: Data Type is Graphic() CCSID 13488

Comment: That seems highly unlikely, unless there are other non-numeric characters in the string. What database engine are we talking about here? (Never mind - I see another comment appeared whilst I was typing this.) I have no idea what Graphic() data type is, but perhaps it's not really a string datatype, and hence the result of SUBSTR or CASTing is not what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to achieve this when the space location is variable, or even when it's fixed and you want to make a more robust query (in case it moves later):

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(LTRIM('00123 45'), 1, CASE WHEN LOCATE(' ', LTRIM('00123 45')) <= 1 THEN LEN('00123 45') ELSE LOCATE(' ', LTRIM('00123 45')) - 1 END) AS BIGINT)
```

If you know the column will always contain a blank space after the start:

```
SELECT CAST(LOCATE(LTRIM('00123 45'), 1, LOCATE(' ', LTRIM('00123 45')) - 1) AS BIGINT)
```

both of these result in:

```
123
```

so your query would

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(LTRIM(myCol1), 1, CASE WHEN LOCATE(' ', LTRIM(myCol1)) <= 1 THEN LEN(myCol1) ELSE LOCATE(' ', LTRIM(myCol1)) - 1 END) AS BIGINT)
FROM myTable1
```

This removes any content after the first space character (ignoring leading spaces), and then converts the remainder to a 64bit integer which will then remove all leading zeroes.

If you want to keep all the numbers and just remove the leading zeroes and any spaces you can use:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('00123 45', ' ', '') AS BIGINT)
```

While my answer might seem quite verbose compared to simply `SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(myCol1, 1, 5) AS BIGINT) FROM myTable1` but it allows for the space character to not always be there, situations where the `myCol1` value is not of the form `nnnnn nn` if the string is `nn nn` then the convert to `int` will fail.

Remember to be careful if you use the `TRIM` function to remove the leading zeroes, and actually in all situations you will need to test your code with data like `00120 00` and see if it returns `12` instead of the correct value of `120`.

Comment: Error: SQL0204 - CHARINDEX in *LIBL type *N not found.

Comment: I didn't notice the DB2 tag, answer updated to use `LOCATE` instead.