# trim value in sql where condition

Tags: java, sql, db2, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a row of records in my db `abc` table, col1 has value '00012345'.

requirement: '00012345' is equal to '12345', trim all the '0' in front.

Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE col1 = '12345';
```

This query will not return me any result, unless I change it to

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE col1 LIKE '%12345';
```

But this will break the rules, for example if my value in db is '00912345',
then '00912345' is not equal to '12345' after trim all the '0' in front.

Kindly advise on how to trim the value in db as well when doing comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091297/remove-leading-zeros)

Comment: Why do you store integer values in character columns?

Comment: Use syntax like below 

Select * from table_1 where LTRIM(name,'0') = '12345';

Answer (score 0):

You can try casting `col1` to a numeric type (e.g. `int`), and then checking equality:

```
SELECT *
FROM abc
WHERE CAST(col1 AS INT) = 12345
```

But if `col1` is storing numeric data, it probably makes better sense to convert that column into a numeric type, rather than `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this DB2, so I assume you're after the DB2 syntax.  It's

```
select * from abc where cast(col1 as integer) = 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version and platform you can try this:

```
 WHERE TRIM(L '0' FROM col1) = '12345'
```

Or this:

```
WHERE LTRIM(col1, '0') = '12345'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution which works on DB2 v9

SELECT * FROM abc WHERE TRIM(L '0' FROM col1) = '12345'

In DB2 v10 it should be also possible to use LTRIM

Answer (score 0):

In my estimation, the OP addresses the difficulty with an improper perspective.

Given that, how the data is stored is known, then just properly compose the literal to match the *rule* about how the data is stored.  Trimming the leading zeroes from every value stored in the database, or casting every value to match a numeric-typed value for selection is IMO, a poor implementation.

We [the readers] might best *assume* that the literal would be coming from user input, and thus the onus can not be placed on any user(s) to reformat their input to match the database.  So instead of the user properly composing the literal value, the next best approach is for the programmer to **modify the literal selection value** to match how the data is stored.

If the character string value '12345' is the specified [user input] value, then an expression can be composed within the query that modifies **only** that literal value.  That would be done rather than composing an expression that casts the column and\or possibly also casting the literal.  For example, with the following givens, one of the possible query WHERE clause variants [expressed using SQL variable syntax] show further below should be helpful:

```
create variable literal_replacement varchar(8) default '12345'
; /* used in place of actual literal string value as user input */
create table abc
( col1  char(08)
) /* My interpretation, as per typical, the OP offers no DDL */
;
create function col1_compare_val
( string_val varchar(08) )
returns char(08)
language sql
 return right( '00000000' concat string_val, 8 )
; /* possible example of encapsulating code to reformat user input */
```

```
WHERE col1 = repeat( '0', 8 - length( literal_replacement ) ) concat literal_replacement

WHERE col1 = ( lpad( literal_replacement, 8, '0' ) )

WHERE col1 = right( '00000000' concat literal_replacement , 8 )

WHERE col1 = col1_compare_val( literal_replacement )
```